# How to capture the return status or exception raised from python logging module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am trying to log some messages to a log file. Inputs of the logger happens to be some unicode strings as well.

Here is an example code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='ReviewReport.log',
                    filemode='w',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

myTestStr = 'My Str is DeltaΔ'

try: 
    logging.info(myTestStr )
except Exception:
    print('In except block....')
    #handle exception by encoding the string.
print('execute rest of the program')
```

When i do this i see below exception on console :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0394' in position 49: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried a lot to understand why my code is not reaching to except block. 'In except block....' does not gets printed but 'execute rest of the program' is printed which makes me feel that logger is not really generating any exception when 'myTestStr' is not logged to my log file.

**My Question is:**

1. Why the UnicodeEncodeError is not caught in except block ? Does logger module not raise any exception.
2. What is correct approach to know if logger was successful in logging the message to file.

Appreciate any support here. Thanks.

Comment: The code is executed correctly. I don't see any problem. Try to add file encoding and see what happen. 
```#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-```

Comment: did you get your solution?

Comment: Thanks Manoj for your response.  I really appreciate. But no i didn't get the solution. On my console i see UnicodeEncodeError (as shown below). I tried adding the # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- but it didn't help. Do you know how can we capture the return status of logging module :                                                          --- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0394' in position 48: character maps to <undefined>
Call stack:
....
execute rest of the program